# Sorting after row reordering in DataTables (jQuery) does not work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with jQuery DataTables and want to allow manual row reordering. Thus I am using [a jQuery plugin that enables row reordering in DataTables](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index).

Problem is that by enabling row reordering, I cannot sort my tables anymore. The programmer of the rowreordering-plugin has made clear that this is how the plugin works, see the discussion here: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/issues/detail?id=1

Now I want to enable sorting even after manual reordering and likewise reordering after sorting. It's not a problem if the sorting destroys the manual order and kind of "reverses" it.

I guess this is the most relevant part of the plugins source code:

```
    return this.each(function () {

        var oTable = $(this).dataTable();

        var aaSortingFixed = (oTable.fnSettings().aaSortingFixed == null ? new Array() : oTable.fnSettings().aaSortingFixed);
        aaSortingFixed.push([properties.iIndexColumn, "asc"]);

        oTable.fnSettings().aaSortingFixed = aaSortingFixed;


        for (var i = 0; i < oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns.length; i++) {
            oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[i].bSortable = false;
            /*for(var j=0; j<aaSortingFixed.length; j++)
            {
            if( i == aaSortingFixed[j][0] )
            oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[i].bSortable = false;
            }*/
        }
        oTable.fnDraw();
```

[Here is the complete source code](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js).

By setting aoColumns[i].bSortable to ´true´ in the for-loop, sorting is enabled in the table but without any effect if I click on the columns. I'm looking for an idea how to fix this issue. The last entry of the [issue discussion](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/issues/detail?id=1) says something promising, but it does not seem to work for me.

I am using DataTables 1.9.0 and jQuery 1.7.1 because the plugin does not work with Datatables 1.10 or jQuery 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dataTables 1.10.x and the new "native" [**RowReorder**](http://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) plugin. Include the following files to your project :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    rowReorder: true
});
```

demo here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/**

Comment: Oh my... I didn't know that! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, thanks. I actually still had the tab open from last week - cannot still get the dragstart / mousemove events to work, not even in alerts.

Comment: Data reorder is not working http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/, Can you tell me what is the reason behind this

Comment: @Deepaksaini - ??? It works here; you drag rows by clicking on the `seq.` column.

Comment: yeah got it, Actually i did this with some other column

Comment: it can not drop when I drop it turn back to before